# Are all $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ irreducible representations faithful?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

For a result I want to obtain I need to know whether there exist non-faithful irreducible representations of 
$\mathfrak{su}(n)$ Lie-algebras. Sadly my expertise in Lie algebra theory is insufficient to answer this question and quick research has revealed a nontrivial connection between irreducibility and faithfulness that is somewhat over my head.

So, do such representations exist and if so can we name an example?

Comment: The trivial representation is the only example since the algebra is simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is simple and since the kernel of a representation is an ideal of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, the only irreducible non-faithful representation of that Lie algebra is the trivial representation on a $1$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: This might be nitpicking, but I think "the" trivial representation actually acts on a one-dimensional vector space, not on $\{0\}$. (It acts *as* $0$ though.) Otherwise we could not write every representation as sum of irreducibles, because if you add zeroes, you never get beyond zero.

Comment: Yes, it is nitpicking. And, more important than that, it is correct. I've edited my answer. Thank you.